# What means ...> in SQL through terminal

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm very new to SQL. I used SQL through my terminal, and wanted to test some commands.
However I don't know what the ...> means when I was trying the `SELECT FROM` command.
It looks like this:

[image]

Can someone explain what the ...> means? Why there's no output from the table?

Comment: probably you need to print `;`

Comment: It thinks you havent finished your SQL. It is expecting more, i.e. `...`. You can try ending the statement with a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...> is just a terminal prompt for continuation of the query from previous line. In your example your command is missing ';' char at the end (which indicates end of the query), therefore it is not executed.

Comment: oh that explains! I just learnt that I have to add ; after my command. Thank you very much!